# Unrecognized selector sent to instance, Storyboard bug after connecting a button to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uistoryboard

I was messing with my storyboard with no code involved and got this error after I connected "Terms of use" button to a view controller. It was working fine before this action.

-I created and connected a class to Terms of Use View Controller

-I used action push segue to connect

[image]

```
2014-01-22 17:26:45.434 Project[1162:a0b] -[AboutViewController termsOfUseButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c89d40
2014-01-22 17:26:45.437 Project[1162:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AboutViewController termsOfUseButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c89d40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173b5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014be8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x017d8903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172b90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0172b4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d0874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
6   UIKit                               0x0022e0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
7   UIKit                               0x0022e04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
8   UIKit                               0x003260c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
9   UIKit                               0x00326484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
10  UIKit                               0x00325733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
11  UIKit                               0x0026b51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
12  UIKit                               0x0026c184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
13  UIKit                               0x0023fe86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
14  UIKit                               0x0022a18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
15  CoreFoundation                      0x016c483f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c41cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
17  CoreFoundation                      0x016e129e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
18  CoreFoundation                      0x016e0ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
19  CoreFoundation                      0x016e08db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
20  GraphicsServices                    0x036909e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
21  GraphicsServices                    0x03690809 GSEventRun + 104
22  UIKit                               0x0022cd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
23  Project                             0x00003a9d main + 141
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d77725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Lame but I found the solution after I finished writing the question)

The reason for this error is I created an IBAction-UIButton method on touch up inside.
I deleted that code and hoped the traces were deleted.
It seems it wasnt, I had to unconnect the touch up inside by clicking the X in red squared spot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try recreating the button and the segue, maybe you changed the IBOutlet name by accident or any other thing.

GL HF